# data-access-token for fecebook (Блок поделиться от Яндекс)

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста, какой именно токен нужно использовать для кнопки шаринга facebook.

А то ссылка дана на [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) где описаны 4 токена, и я не могу понять какой именно мне нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен *Маркер доступа к приложению*

> Этот маркер позволяет считывать и изменять настройки приложения. Он также может применяться для публикации действий Open Graph.

Счётчики Фейсбука забираются через Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&access_token={accessToken}
```